# Proof of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/ \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules, tensor-products

I've just started to learn about the tensor product and I want to show: $$(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/ \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}.$$

Can you tell me if my proof is right:

$\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ are both finite free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules with the basis consisting of one single element $\{ 1 \}$. So $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$ has the basis $\{ 1 \otimes 1 \}$.

Therefore, any element in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$  is of the form $(ab) 1 \otimes 1$ and any element in $\mathbb{Z}/ \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $k 1 = k$ where $k \in \{ 0, \dots , \gcd(n,m) \}$.

I would like to construct an isomorphism that maps $ab$ to some $k$. Let this map be $ab (1 \otimes 1) \mapsto ab \bmod \gcd(n,m)$.

This is a homomorphism between modules: it maps $0$ to $0$ because it maps the empty sum to the empty sum. It also fulfills $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ because there is only one element, $a = 1$.

It is surjective. So all I need to show is that it is injective. But that is clear too because if $ab \equiv 0 \bmod \gcd(m,n)$  then both $a \equiv 0 \bmod n$ and $b \equiv 0 \bmod m$ so the kernel is trivial.

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Careful:  $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is not free as $\mathbb{Z}$-module!  However, you can say that the module is generated by $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ (though technically, $\{1\}$ is not a basis, because the module is not free).

Comment: Hint: If $d=mx+ny$, then $d(1\otimes 1) = x(m1 \otimes 1) + y(1\otimes n1) = 0$.

Comment: @ShaunAult: thanks! I'm not sure I understand why I cannot treat $1$ as a basis though... Could you tell me more please?

Comment: $\{1\}$ is not a basis because it is not linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ : $m \cdot 1 = 0$.

Comment: @Ted is correct:  To be a basis, a set has to be spanning and independent.  $\{1\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is spanning, but not independent.  However, you can still use $1$ in the way you want to.  You don't need to use linear independence; all that you need is that it generates the module.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The part that is missing is pretty much the essence of the following (incomplete) alternative proof.

Determine the kernel of
$$
  \begin{array}{rlrl}
    g: & \mathbb{Z} & \rightarrow & (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})
    \\
       & z          & \to         & z (1 \otimes 1)
  \end{array}
$$
That is: When is it true that $z (1 \otimes 1)$ is null? Since it is true for $z \in m\mathbb{Z} \cup n\mathbb{Z}$, then you know that it is true for the ideal generated by it: $\langle \mathrm{gcd}(m,n)\rangle \subset \mathrm{ker}(g)$.

You know that the map is surjective because $1 \otimes 1$ is a generator. If you show that $\mathrm{ker}(g) \subset \langle \mathrm{gcd}(m,n) \rangle$, you will have the isomorphism you claim. This is the part you are missing. It is equivalent to showing that your $f$ is well-defined.

So, the conclusion is that it is not right.

Comment: Well let $x \in \mathrm{ker}(g)$. Then $g(x) = x(1 \otimes 1) = 0 \otimes 0$. Hence if $x$ was not already zero it is either a multiple of $n$ or a multiple of $m$ and hence in $\langle \mathrm{gcd}(m,n) \rangle$.

Comment: @Matt:  Careful:  If $m=6$ and $n=4$, then $x = 2\in \ker(g)$ but $x$ isn't a multiple of $4$ or $6$.  What's happening is $2(1\otimes 1) = (6-4)(1\otimes 1) = 6(1\otimes 1) -4(1\otimes 1) = 6\otimes 1 - 1\otimes 4 = 0-0=0$

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you. Right. So to fix my proof of $\subset$, do I make two cases: $x$ divides either $m$ or $n$ or $x$ is a multiple of either $m$ or $n$? Or is there a nicer way to show $\subset$?

Comment: @Matt:  I don't know a particularly elegant solution, but here goes.  Consider the bilinear map $\mathbb{Z}_m\times \mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\gcd(m,n)}$ sending $(x,y)$ to $xy \bmod{\gcd(m,n)}$.  By universal property of tensor products, this factors through $\mathbb{Z}_m\otimes\mathbb{Z}_n$.  Using this, one can show the element $k(1\otimes 1)\neq 0$ for every $0<k < \gcd(m,n)$.  Finally, going back to $\subset$, if $x$ isn't a multiple of $\gcd(m,n)$, write $x = s\gcd(m,n) + k$ with $0<k<\gcd(m,n)$.  Show that $g(x) = g(k)$ and conclude that $g(k)\neq 0$, so $g(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you! But if you use the universal property, the linear map $l$ you get goes from $(\mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$ to $\mathbb Z / \mathrm{gcd}(m,n) \mathbb Z$, that is, it's the inverse of the induced map $\bar{g} : \mathbb Z / \mathrm{gcd}(m,n)\mathbb Z \to (\mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$. Then instead of obtaining $g(x) \neq 0$ we obtain $l(x) = \bar{g}^{-1}(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Matt:  I'm just using the universal property to better understand the elements of the tensor product.  The point is you have this element $k(1\otimes 1)$ with $0<k<\gcd(m,n)$ and you don't know if this is actually $0$ due to some weird combination of relations.  To rule this out, I find a linear map out of the tensor product which maps $k(1\otimes 1)$ to something nonzero.  Since a linear map always maps $0$ to $0$, this proves $k(1\otimes 1)$ is nonzero.  Once you know this is nonzero, go back to $g(x)$.  (continued)

Comment: @Matt: (continued).  If $x$ is *not* in the ideal generated by $\gcd(m,n)$, then $x = s\gcd(m,n) + k$ with $0<k<\gcd(m,n)$.  First show $g(x) = g(k)$, but then $g(k) = k(1\otimes 1)$ is nonzero by the previous comment.  This shows $g(x)$ is *not* in the kernel.  Contrapostively, what we've proved is if $x$ is in the kernel of $g$, then $x$ is in the ideal generated by $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Dear Jason. Thank you very much for your help! I know decided to proof this fact in a different, slightly easier way, using the universal property. I posted it as an answer. Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 50):

The better way to define a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$ is via the universal property.

Note that the map $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $$(x+m\mathbb{Z},y+n\mathbb{Z})\mapsto xy+\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$$ is well-defined and also bi-linear, thus by the universal property of tensor product, there is a linear map $f:\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$f(x+m\mathbb{Z}\otimes y+n\mathbb{Z})=xy+\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}.$$ Verify that the linear map $g:\mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$$g(z+\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z})=(z+m\mathbb{Z})\otimes (1+n\mathbb{Z})$$
is well-defined, and we also have  $g\circ f=1, f\circ g=1$, thus $f$ is an isomorphism. To see  $g$ is well-defined, you may use the equality that $\gcd(m,n)=am+bn$ for some integers $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 26):

Let $M$ be a $R$-module and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Then we have $\frac RI\otimes_RM\cong\frac M{IM}$.

First proof: consider the exact sequence $0\to I\to R\to\frac RI\to0$. Tensoring with $M$ and using right-exactness of the tensor product we get $I\otimes_RM\to R\otimes_RM\to\frac RI\otimes_RM\to0$. We know that $R\otimes_RM\cong M$ via $r\otimes m\mapsto rm$; under this isomorphism the image of $I\otimes_RM\to R\otimes_RM$ is precisely $IM$, and since this image is precisely the kernel of $R\otimes_RM\to\frac RI\otimes_RM$, the claim follows from the isomorphism theorem.

Second proof: the mapping $\frac RI\times M\to\frac M{IM}$ given by $(r+I,m)\mapsto rm+IM$ is well-defined and $R$-bilinear, so it induces a $R$-linear mapping $\frac RI\otimes_RM\to\frac M{IM}$, which is obviously surjective, and the inverse mapping is given by $m+IM\mapsto(1+I)\otimes m$; this mapping is well-defined because if $m\in IM$, say $m=\sum_k i_km_k$, with $i_k\in I, m_k\in M$, then by $R$-bilinearity of $\otimes$ we have $(1+I)\otimes m=\sum_k\bigl[i_k(1+I)\bigr]\otimes m_k=\sum_k0_{R/I}\otimes m_k=0$.

In general, if $N$ is a $R$-submodule of a module $M$, then

$$I\frac MN=\frac{IM+N}N\,,$$

so

$$m\mathbb Z\,\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}=\frac{(m\mathbb Z)\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}=\frac{m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}=\frac{\gcd(m,n)\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}\,.$$

Finally, applying the first result we get

$$\frac{\mathbb Z}{m\mathbb Z}\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}\cong\frac{\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}}{m\mathbb Z\,\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}}=\frac{\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}}{\,\frac{\gcd(m,n)\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}\,}\cong\frac{\mathbb Z}{\gcd(m,n)\mathbb Z}\,.$$

**ADDENDUM**

The same reasoning shows that for any ideals $I,J$ in $R$ we have $\frac RI\otimes_R\frac RJ\cong\frac R{I+J}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $R\otimes_RM\cong M$ at the beginning of the third line of your second paragraph? Also, could you tell me in a little bit more detail what you mean by 'under this isomorphism the image of $I\otimes_R M \rightarrow R\otimes_R M$ is precisely $IM$'? I don't know what the isomorphism has to do with the maps in the diagram since there are only maps between tensor products. Could you elaborate on that? I would really like to understand your proof since it seems very elegant.

Comment: @see You are right about the second paragraph; I will correct it now. Regarding your question, what I mean is that the image of the composite map $I\otimes_RM\to R\otimes_RM\to M$ is precisely $IM$.

Answer (score 12):

Claim: $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/ \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$

---

Proof:

We show the claim by showing that $(\mathbb{Z}/ \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}, b)$, where $$b: \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/ \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$$ is the map $(a,b) \mapsto ab \bmod \mathrm{gcd} (n,m)$ satisfies the universal property of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}) $, that is, for any $\mathbb Z$-module $P$ and any bilinear map 
$b^\prime : \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z} \to P$ there exists a unique linear map $l$ such that $l \circ b = b^\prime$.

Define $l: (a \bmod \mathrm{gcd} (n,m)) \mapsto b^\prime (1,a) $. Linearity of $l$ directly follows from bilinearity of $b^\prime$. For $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ we have $l(b(a,b)) = l(ab) = b^\prime (1,ab) = b^\prime (a,b) $ so that $l$ indeed makes the diagram commute.

To finish the proof we check that $l$ is unique. To this end let $l^\prime$ be such that $l^\prime \circ b = b^\prime$. Then $l(a) = l(b(1,a)) = b^\prime (1,a) = l^\prime (b(1,a)) = l^\prime (a)$, hence the claim follows.

Comment: I like this because it lets me avoid fiddling with numbers.

Comment: Why do you know that $l$ is well-defined? Why don't you call your functions $f$ and $f'$ instead of $b$ and $b'$?

Comment: @AndréCaldas Yes, should of course verify that it's well-defined! $b$ stands for bilinear.

Comment: Just checking, but, is this not a stronger claim then what you originally asked for? Originally you asked for $\mathbb{Z}/(m) \otimes \mathbb{Z}/(n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/\text{gcd}(m,n)$, so any old isomorphism would do, but your proof above actually shows that $\mathbb{Z}/\text{gcd}(m,n)$ $\textit{is}$ the tensor product. Which certainly proves the claim since then it is uniquely isomorphic making the diagram commute, thus also isomorphic in general

Answer (score 9):

The only thing that you are missing is to show that your map is well-defined.  Indeed, we implicitly make a choice of representatives when we write $a \otimes b$ or $ab(1 \otimes 1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  So we first need to show that if $a \equiv c \bmod m$ and $b \equiv d \bmod n$, then the image of $c \otimes d$ is the same under your map.  That is, we need to show $cd \equiv ab \bmod gcd(m, n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Perform operation $-\otimes \mathbb Z_n$ on exact sequence
$$\mathbb Z\overset m\longrightarrow\mathbb Z\longrightarrow\mathbb Z_m\longrightarrow0$$
to get a new exact sequence
$$\mathbb Z_n\overset m\longrightarrow\mathbb Z_n\longrightarrow\mathbb Z_m\otimes \mathbb Z_n\longrightarrow0.$$
Therefore
$$\mathbb Z_m\otimes \mathbb Z_n\cong{\rm coker}(\mathbb Z_n\overset m\longrightarrow\mathbb Z_n)\cong\mathbb Z_{\gcd(m,n)}.$$