# What is the tensor product of Z/10Z with Z/12Z?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, self-learning, tensor-products

I've just met tensor products of modules in part of my self-study and as a concrete exercise I've been asked to calculate $\mathbb{Z}/(10){\otimes}_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/(12)$. Short of writing out each symbol $m\otimes n$ and finding which ones are equal to each other, is there a good way to do this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72284/proof-of-mathbbz-m-mathbbz-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbz-n-mathbbz